# How do I pass in a string with spaces into PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Given:

```
# test1.ps1
param(
    $x = "",
    $y = ""
)

&echo $x $y
```

Used like so:

```
powershell test.ps1
```

Outputs:

```
> <blank line>
```

But then this goes wrong:

```
test.ps1 -x "Hello, World!" -y "my friend"
```

Outputs:

```
Hello,
my
```

I was expecting to see:

```
Hello, World! my friend
```

Comment: That works from the powershell prompt for me but fails from cmd.exe. Which makes this a cmd.exe limitation. Using single quotes there instead seems to work... which is strange because I didn't think cmd.exe dealt with single quotes at all.

Comment: So is this a powershell question or a cmd.exe question? It seems you've answered your own question perhaps?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Well, this is a `cmd.exe` problem, but there are some ways to solve it.

1. Use single quotes

   ```
   powershell test.ps1 -x 'hello world' -y 'my friend'
   ```
2. Use the `-file` argument

   ```
   powershell -file test.ps1 -x "hello world" -y "my friend"
   ```
3. Create a `.bat` wrapper with the following content

   ```
   @rem test.bat
   @powershell -file test.ps1 %1 %2 %3 %4
   ```

   And then call it:

   ```
   test.bat -x "hello world" -y "my friend"
   ```

Comment: I had this issue with running a PowerShell script from a scheduled task in Windows. One of the parameters of the script was used to build a path and had a space in it, and the script failed because it dropped everything after the space. Adding the `-File` argument fixed the issue.

Comment: `-File- did not work, I solved it by directly quoting the arg `%1` and escaping the quote which gives: `\"%1\"` . I can then use the `$arg` without any problem (the path doesn't break anymore at the first space)

Comment: `-File` helps with a script whose filename contains spaces. However, it affects how PowerShell parses the remaining commandline. An argument `-` produces a weird error (probably a PowerShell bug), as does `-:`. Arguments with parentheses previously had to be put in single quotes; now those have to be removed, otherwise they are passed on to the script. PowerShell 5.1.

Comment: -File works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

One can use a backtick ` to escape spaces:

```
PS & C:\Program` Files\\....
```

Comment: Or as mentioned above escape the quotes in the command line, e.g. powershell somefile \"arg with space\"

Answer (score 7):

A possible solution was in my case to nest the single and the double quotes.

```
test.ps1 -x '"Hello, World!"' -y '"my friend"'
```

Comment: I was trying to run java application with multiple profiles like `profile1,profile2` and your solution was the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem but in my case I was trying to run a cmdlet, and the call was being made within a Cake script.  In this case the single quotes and `-file` argument did not work:

```
powershell Get-AuthenticodeSignature 'filename with spaces.dll'
```

Resulting error: `Get-AuthenticodeSignature : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'with'.`

I wanted to avoid the batch file if possible.

**Solution**

What did work was to use a cmd wrapper with /S to unwrap outer quotes:

```
cmd /S /C "powershell Get-AuthenticodeSignature 'filename with spaces.dll'"
```