# Powershell ignores new parameters

Tags: powershell, parameters

I have powershell script with input parameters, but when I run it, some input is ignored and script just uses same parameters as in previous run.

I assume ps remembers some frequent parameters in cache, is there a way how to force it to always take new parameters?

Called with

```
-ExecutionPolicy bypass 
-command xxx.ps1
-subject "Report: xxx"
-from "xxx@yyy.com"
-fordate "xxxx-xx-xx"
-path "xxx\"
-fileName "xxx.zip"
```

Parameter declaration in script

```
Param(
  $subject,
  $from,
  [DateTime]$fordate,
  $path,
  $fileName
)
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you show us the parameter definition of the script and show us how you run it?

Comment: I think the code is definitely relevant here, please post what you've got.

Comment: I have included parameter definition and how i run it in post

Comment: Please don't put tags or commentary in a subject.

Comment: But I cant accept my own answer as solved yet and I dont really see point in wasting time of other people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with one parameter that was split with space (for example 'report: xxx'), even though it was separated in commas, powershell only took the part before space (which was same for all cases - thats why i thought it didnt take new parameter).

I have fixed the problem with using -file instead of -command at the start ([How to pass in a string with spaces into PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311191/how-to-pass-in-a-string-with-spaces-into-powershell))

I think I will delete this question later because it is not the problem which was described in title/post (has zero value for future users i guess), but i still want to thank all people that commented or took a minute to think about it